# Bayesian Network, conditional probability distribution

Tags: bayesian

New to Bayesian network, my question is to how to use conditional probability distribution in each node with directed acyclic graph

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: sorry, I want to make my network with probability at each node how to make this possible

Comment: I am uisng MSBNx for making my Bayesian network, but stuck with the probability distribution.